# How to extract string between two special characters in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am using a query to extract number between special characters from database.

```
select number from database where number between like '<%' and '%>'"
```

How to write MySQL script to get `101` out of `<101>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to achieve this.

**Query**

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(num,'>',1),'<',-1) AS extracted
FROM table_name;
```

[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4fb5/1)