# How to Extract only email id in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to extract only Email Id from the below example (i.e. abc@abc.com, mno@mno.com, etc.)? Each row can contains multiple Email IDs...

```
"ABC" <abc@abc.com>; "XYZ" <xyz@xyz.com>; pqr@pqr.com; "MNO" <mno@mno.com>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract string between two special characters in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979061/how-to-extract-string-between-two-special-characters-in-mysql)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28979204/911550

Comment: Please tag your question appropriately: you name SQL Server in the subject and use both mysql and sql-server tags.

Comment: sorry for that,I need SQL SERVER QUERY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *MySQL* you could use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` in following:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Id, '>', 1), '<', -1) Email
FROM Tbl;
```

In *SQL Server* will be:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Id, CHARINDEX('<', Id) + 1 , CHARINDEX('>', Id) - CHARINDEX('<', Id) - 1)
FROM Tbl;
```

Comment: what is num in your Query

Comment: It is column name, should be `Id` instead, check now. Replace `Id` with your `ColumnName`

Comment: it's working but returns only one email id , rows contains multiplt emails id's

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'>',1),'<',-1) AS EmailID
FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

In sql server run this query

```
SELECT SUBSTRING ( Emailcolumn ,CHARINDEX('<',Emailcolumn )+1
 , CHARINDEX('>',Emailcolumn )-CHARINDEX('<',Emailcolumn )-1)
```

Comment: This wont work in SQL-Server, It will return results like `abc@abc.com>;` with additional symbols in the end of string.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas Now check

Comment: Now your code is identical to mine, in this case It will work.

Comment: I had multiple email id's multiple To,CC and Bcc,above query only returns first email id i.e. abc@abc.com not remaining.